# Discord.js: How read users status with a bot on server?

Tags: node.js

I wrote a little bot and need the status(Online,Offline,Idle) of all users on the server. I found https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=users

```
bot.on('ready', function() { console.log(bot.users); });
```

This show all users with:

```
'352....128': User { username: 'NAME', id: '352....128', discriminator: '5000' avatar: null, bot: false },
```

So there is no status. The Bot have no access for this? In embed.js I can read the status of all online and idle users (offline users are not listed): https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/SERVERID/embed.json

```
{"username": "NAME", "status": "online", "nick": "NICK", "avatar_url": "...", "avatar": "...", "discriminator": "5000", "id": "..."}
```

Is embed.json the only way to get the status of all online and idle users? So I need to install this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile and read this file?

Comment: Please let me know if it works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find it here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus

You can either use:

```
user.presence.status
```

or:

```
member.user.presence.status
```

It's returns "online", "idle", "dnd" or "offline"

Answer (score 2):

Or even simpler :

```
.addField('Status', message.author.presence.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your bot to set the status by itself, for example

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setStatus("online");
});        


client.on("disconnected", () => {
    client.user.setStatus("offline");
    console.log(client.user); //returns the current user
});

console.log(client.users); //returns all users
```

To see all client events, please see [here](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#events)

**Update**

```
client.on("message", function(msg){
    if(client.user.isAdmin){ //checking as an admin for example
      if(msg.content == "-showUsers"){
         client.deleteMessage(msg, callBackFunc);
         console.log(bot.users);
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! What is with users that are already on server? You only catch new connections and disconnection and what is with "idle" status? :)

Comment: I have made a small piece of code as an update, I don't know if it'd work, but it's basically typing a command in the channel to retrieve all users :) Please let me know if it works. I am not too sure. @user706420

Answer (score -7):

```js
var KlausAlge = "Klaus Alge"

for (KlausAlge in map) return true
for (!KlausAlge in map) return false
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation as to how any why your answer is a good solution and how it works as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26376569)

Comment: Enter an explanation to how your code should work. The code is not obviouse. It seems it doesn't solve the question, so please edit the question and write an explanation of ho your  code works

Comment: Trolling be like