# Discord.js: Can you filter online and offline users then add them to an array?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I was wondering if you can take the UserID's from an array, filter them by who is online and add the online members to a variable.

The way most people say on discord is to do something like this but I tried a few different things but they all didn't work, any ideas?

```
  var staff = [
    //List of staff ID's will be added here
    
  ]

  var onlinestaff = staff.filter(/*Check if their status is online*/)
```

Comment: What did you try?
Can you provide actual an example?

Comment: A couple of things like `staff.presence === "Online"` and `staff.status === "Online"` but with these it was immediately clear that it wasn't searching for the user first, I got stuck after that and no one is answering on discord so I came here.

Comment: Try to `console.log` staff, so you can figure out what field to check

Comment: No Im adding the staff ID's manually, I just removed them for their privacy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the total of members online/offline Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024871/find-the-total-of-members-online-offline-discord-js)

Comment: Kind of, I just need to check the user ID's that would be in the staff array not the entire server, Ill try to change that code and will reply with an answer.

Comment: This is the closest I can get but the error is that presence is undefined.

`var onlinestaff = message.guild.members.cache.filter(staff.id.presence.status == "Online")`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var staffids = [ "736230247556579438", "721834376794472540" ]

var onlineusers = [];

staffids.forEach(async function(u) {
    const uu = await client.users.fetch(u)
    if(uu.presence.status == "online") {
        onlineusers.push(uu.username)
    } else {
        return
    }
})
```

Also sorry for the variable names, I did this as fast as possible.

Comment: I edited the variable names and there are no errors but when you run the command the variable `onlinestaff` is still empty.

Comment: Did you also add your staff ID's?

Comment: Yes, I also changed online to Online but that didnt work either.